# Can a Spring MVC controller return both a HttpServletResponse and a view?

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

My existing code is like:

```
String myController(@PathVariable someId, ModelMap map){
....
return "myViewName";
}
```

Now I want to set a cookie in some cases, so I need to get hold of a HttpServletResponse obj. Can I just add such a response obj to the list of params and operate on it in the controller? 
If so, I wonder how my own response is kind of reconciled with the response generated by the JSP that resolves the "myViewName".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

```
@RequestMapping
public String myController(@PathVariable someId, ModelMap map, HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Do what you need to do on the response, like set a cookie
    return "myViewName";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your other question :  "how my own response is kind of reconciled with the response generated by the JSP that resolves the "myViewName"."

When you return a view say "myViewName", it will be resolved to a particular resource (JSP View or JSON View or any other view). Once that view resource is obtained depending on what you return, that view does the rendering on to the response. This response object is the same that was passed to the controller function (myController). So say if you set some cookie/headers on the response in the controller function, the response that is being used by the view to do the rendering will also have the same properties.

In case you want to handle the actual rendering/response yourself, you can always get the outputstream of the response and write to it and close the stream. Then the view that you return is just ignored as the dispatcher will check that the response is already handled and will just do post handle stuff.

Hope that clears up for anyone looking for the dispatcher logic behind it.